# Detect Browser on Ipad - Chrome or Safari

Tags: c#, asp.net, browser, asp.net-core-mvc, user-agent

I need to find out which browser ipads are using to set the proper css files.
I am checking if its an ipad using the `Request.Headers["User-Agent"]` containing the word `ipad` or `iphone`.
 Now I need to know which browser is being used. **Chrome** or **Safari**. 
 **How can I do this?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working by using the http://useragentstring.com/pages/api.php.

```
var userAgent = Context.Request.Headers["User-Agent"];
var url = "http://www.useragentstring.com/?uas=" + userAgent + "&getText=agent_name";
HttpWebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.CreateHttp(url);

    req.PreAuthenticate = true;
    var res = req.GetResponse();
    var text = "";
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        text = sr.ReadToEnd();
    }
    res.Close();

    if (text.Contains("Safari"))
    {
        //do stuff here
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you use the [HTTPRequest](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Web.HttpRequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class?

With [HttpRequest.Browser](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.browser%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can get a lot of information about the browser including the name.

```
HttpBrowserCapabilities bc = Request.Browser;
string browserName = bc.Browser;
```

If you need to use the [UserAgent](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httprequest.useragent%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), you can also check the browser name.

```
String userAgent;
userAgent = Request.UserAgent;
if (userAgent.IndexOf("MSIE 6.0") > -1) 
{
   // The browser is Microsoft Internet Explorer Version 6.0.
}
```

Comment: what would I use to check for Safari and Chrome? Those are the 2 that I need

Comment: @MB If you are using the UserAgent, you can make a API call to http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/api.php. Once you get the browser name from either HttpRequest method, you can do a string compare.

Comment: this is returning  a Safari agent_type for both safari and chrome. any other ideas?

Comment: @MB On this page http://www.useragentstring.com/pages/Safari/, none of the User Agents contain "Chrome". After a few test I ran using the API, the Safari user agents did not return "Chrome" inside the agent_Name return value. Maybe do a String Contain to check for "Chrome"?

Comment: The problem is not with Safari. The problem is that all chrome useragents return safari as the browser and do not contain the work chrome anywhere in the useragent. My answer below does not work because it returns true for chrome as well. This is refering to chrome on ipads

Comment: @MB Can you provide the user agent string you are using?